# How often should I clean my apartment?

Tags: hygiene

I understand that opinions differ viz cleaning frequency for subjective reasons: for example, some hate seeing dust, others don’t mind; some clean mostly for social reasons.

But are there some studies about objective reasons for (or against?) cleaning your apartment (wrt health)?

I am especially interested in long-term, or very sudden and bad, consequences, that I might not observe until it is too late. Is more frequent cleaning correlated with lower incidence of problematic illnesses, for example?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is blatantly off-topic and has nothing to do with Health.

Comment: People with asthma are advised to vacuum their houses at least once a day, while living in a sterile environment has been linked to the development of allergies. So there are known health aspects to cleaning.

Comment: Cleanliness is related to hygiene and disease prevention. (As the tag “hygiene” on this very web site indicates, and as the comment by @Count Iblis illustrates.) Can you explain how you reach the conclusion that my question has nothing to do with health? Maybe I should rephrase something, if it is unclear?

Comment: I agree with @CountIblis. You might state something like: "For some conditions, frequently cleaning is advised, such as vacuuming for asthma or washing sheets on hot water for allergic rhintiis.  Other conditions are thought to be associated with environments that are too sterile.  Is there an evidence-based recommendation for "how clean" one's home environment should be?"  I realize this is a broad question but at least the root of it could be answered reasonably concisely.

Comment: One could talk about not cleaning showers or damp areas that can lead to mold, and there are some molds that can cause allergies or even (rarely) lung inflammation.  Usually that's when in larger quantities like water damaged furniture.  And that scrubbing with bleach kills even the spores but if you clean more regularly it won't build up in the first place...

Comment: @CountIblis I am aware of this. Nonetheless, a good answer to *how often should I clean my apartment* will have to dwell into different cleansing techniques and types of dust, which is both off-topic. Even if we accept that, the question is still too broad (*bad effects of not cleaning my house*) and I'd opt to close this as well.

Comment: @DoctorWhom That's the start of a pretty good answer. Nonetheless, it feels that this would be a very broad answer to a very broad question. I like your proposal question. (*how clean should my home environment be*) because this would not go into cleaning. Another option to make this more on-topic and less broad is invoking a certain medical condition (*cleaning house for person with allergies/asthma/skin conditions etc*)

Comment: All these comments and suggestions are great ways to **improve the question** so it is not off-topic any more. If you want to perform those gyrations, go ahead. It would be wrong for an answer to do so. The question **as asked** is not about health. Feel free to make it about health so it can be answered.

Comment: I would think there should be a component that also addresses the safety and type of cleaning agents used when talking about frequent cleaning.  Not only an dust and mold trigger issues for those with asthma and allergies, but so can the products used particularly of used often and in large areas.

Comment: Let’s discuss the concerns one by one, because I do not understand them (and thus can’t rephrase the question).
@Narusan Can you explain how dwelling “into different cleansing techniques and types of dust” would be OT? If related to health, it seems to me quite on topic. I can easily imagine that some cleaning techniques are better than others, wrt health. If I understand correctly that’s even illustrated by DoctorWhom’s answer: “scrubbing with bleach kills even the spores but if you clean more regularly it won't build up in the first place”.

Comment: @Nasran regarding the question being too broad: it currently appears very difficult to me to meaningfully restrict it without making it a personal request for medical advice (which would be considered to be the case, probably, if asking for cleaning advices for persons with allergies/asthma/skin conditions). DoctorWhom wrote that the root of the question could be answered reasonably concisely. Why not proceed?

Comment: @Nasran Asking for “how clean should my home environment be” sounds even broader to me than the current question. It includes questions such as how often should the “environment” be cleaned; and “home environment” includes “apartment”, I suppose, and possibly more.

Comment: I specified in the title and text of the question that it’s about health. I hope that’s what is asked for.